# Showing that a set of vectors is linearly independent if the induced matrix of inner products between those vectors is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

I'm working on the following problem:

> Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional real vector space, and let $( , )$ be a positive definite inner product on $V$. Show that elements $v_1,\ldots,v_m \in V$ are linearly independent if and only if the $m \times m$ matrix $A = (a_{i,j})$ given by $a_{ij} = (v_i, v_j)$ is non-singular.

I have figured out the first direction, but not the second. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I would be surprised if this doesn't turn out to be a duplicate question since it's a common construction - e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix .  But until it's properly marked as such: hint - $A \begin{bmatrix} c_1 \\ \vdots \\ c_m \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \langle v_1, \sum c_i v_i \rangle \\ \vdots \\ \langle v_m, \sum c_i v_i \rangle \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Using Daniel's comment, show that if $\sum_k a_k v_k = 0$ then $Ax=0$.